# 'Communication with Apple' error when building flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, build, release

I tried to make a build release of an Ios flutter project but I got an error. This happens when I try to select a team identifier, the bundle appears normal but never completes the operation.

Here is the error message:

"Communication with Apple failed
Your team has no devices from which to generate a provisioning profile. Connect a device to use or manually add device IDs in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
https://developer.apple.com/account/

No profiles for 'br.com.portalcri.crisports' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'br.com.portalcri.crisports'."

I bought a developer account.

The bundle was created and appeared here but didn't verify my team.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need a device registered in your developer account. Follow the instructions Either get the udid of a physical device and add it to your developer account or connect the device to your Mac, open Xcode and build a project with "automatic signing"; that will add the device to your developer account.